# Can't connect to samba on public ip

Tags: networking, ubuntu, iptables, samba

Currently Samba is installed on my Ubuntu server and sharing folders normally with a windows server, both are sharing a private network on Gogrid,

But now i am trying to share the same folder to another Ubuntu server on Linode using the Ubuntu Gogrid public IP, but the Samba ports aren't reachable when trying to nmap from the Linode (not shown at all),

And when i tried to flush the iptables on the samba server (gogrid), i got both ports shown and filtered,

```
PORT     STATE    SERVICE
21/tcp   open     ftp
80/tcp   open     http
139/tcp  filtered netbios-ssn
443/tcp  open     https
445/tcp  filtered microsoft-ds
```

Any help please?

And if there is a probability that Gogrid already blocked both ports on public access, how can i change samba default ports?

Comment: You are attempting this outside of your network right?  You will be unable to test if it's working, if you are using your public ip address, within your own network.

Comment: Yes exactly outside my network on another host using both public IPs